# Auto Check Tick box based on certain Criteria in Access

Tags: date, ms-access

I've got a table called tblBooking which includes details about 8 van bookings. One of the fields is the Return date formatted as dd/mm/yyyy. Another of the fields in the table is a yes or no data type tick box. Im struggling on how to make the tick box automatically be checked for the records where the "Return date" is greater the todays date e.g Date()

Answer (score 1):

If you want to automatically check a check box in a table field, the short answer is "don't do it" because you are violating a rule of Normalization by creating a field that is a function of another field. That check box field should not be part of your table design: it should appear on a form or report but not be stored in the table.

If you are referring to a check box on a form or report, you can put your field in the underlying query as a calculated field. Create a column in the query. See attached for the query design. 
[image: See attached]

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a query not to say a field in your table - just use this expression as *ControlSource* for your checkbox on your form or report:

```
=CBool([ReturnDate]>Date())
```